# What "Logical Query Operator/s" should I use to merge two separate queries?

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-accounts

What **Logical Query Operator/s** do I use to join ***TWO*** queries yielding documents that belong to the **logged in user** `Meteor.userId();` **AND** all documents that have the **logged in user**'s phone number in the `recipientNumber` variable.

Document's holding the **logged in users** phone number in the `recipientNumber` variable, suggests that the **logged in user**'s are a *Recipient* of funds.

For reference, find below a *logged in users* details:

```
var user = Meteor.userId();      
var userDetails = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: user}, { fields: { "profile.telephoneNumber": 1, "profile.name": 1 } } ); 

var usersNumber = userDetails.profile.telephoneNumber;
var userName = userDetails.profile.name;

console.log("Users _id is: " +user);
console.log("Users Number is: " +usersNumber);
console.log("Users Name is: " +userName);
```

The code above correctly yields:

```
Users _id is: "sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG"
Users Number is: +254705086633
Users Name is: Sir.BT
```

`recipientsDetails.find({ }).fetch();` shows the contents of the collection in subject:

```
0:
payersName: "The LucidOreo"
payersUserId: "KDJFGkCRF3E5nY37e"
recipientNumber: "+254705086633"
_id: "MMyinrcrrYpz2haxq"    
1:
payersName: "Sir.BT"
payersUserId: "sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG"
recipientNumber: "+254705086633"
_id: "YbPFT9ecCA4FTgqsn"

2:
payersName: "Sir.BT"
payersUserId: "sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG"
recipientNumber: "+254705577633"
_id: "ZPWNsQ7TWSJcERSJv"
```

The query below filters the collection, to show only the documents that belong to the user based on the users **Meteor.userId()** being: **sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG**.

```
var user = Meteor.userId(); 
recipientsDetails.find( {payersUserId: user} ).fetch();
```

Find below the results:

```
0:
payersName: "Sir.BT"
payersUserId: "sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG"
recipientNumber: "+254705086633"
_id: "YbPFT9ecCA4FTgqsn"


1:
payersName: "Sir.BT"
payersUserId: "sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG"
recipientNumber: "+254705577633"
_id: "ZPWNsQ7TWSJcERSJv"
```

I would like to formulate a query that shows a combination of **TWO** things:

All the documents that belong to the logged in user (as illustrated in code below):

```
var user = Meteor.userId(); 
recipientsDetails.find( {payersUserId: user} ).fetch();
```

...and all the documents that carry the phone number of the logged in user (also as illustrated in code below):

```
var user = Meteor.userId();      
 var userDetails = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: user}, { fields {"profile.telephoneNumber": 1 } } ); 

 var usersNumber = userDetails.profile.telephoneNumber;

 recipientsDetails.find( {recipientNumber: usersNumber} ).fetch();
```

What Logical Query Operator/s should I use in a query to yield this?

I have tried out:

```
var user = Meteor.userId();

var userDetails = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: user}, { fields: { "profile.telephoneNumber": 1 } } ); 

var usersNumber = userDetails.profile.telephoneNumber; 

recipientsDetails.find( { $and: [{payersUserId: user},  {recipientNumber: usersNumber }  ] }  ).fetch();
```

Unfortunately this erroneously yields:

```
0:
payersName: "Sir.BT"
payersUserId: "sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG"
recipientNumber: "+254705086633"
_id: "YbPFT9ecCA4FTgqsn"

1:
payersName: "Sir.BT"
payersUserId: "sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG"
recipientNumber: "+254705577633"
_id: "ZPWNsQ7TWSJcERSJv"
```

...and leaves out:

```
payersName: "The LucidOreo"
payersUserId: "KDJFGkCRF3E5nY37e"
recipientNumber: "+254705086633"
_id: "MMyinrcrrYpz2haxq"
```

...which clearly carries the `recipientNumber: "+254705086633"` **the logged in users** number.

To clarify, the desired yield would be:

```
0:
payersName: "The LucidOreo"
payersUserId: "KDJFGkCRF3E5nY37e"
recipientNumber: "+254705086633"
_id: "MMyinrcrrYpz2haxq"    
1:
payersName: "Sir.BT"
payersUserId: "sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG"
recipientNumber: "+254705086633"
_id: "YbPFT9ecCA4FTgqsn"

2:
payersName: "Sir.BT"
payersUserId: "sxY3fsY9LmJYqFkiG"
recipientNumber: "+254705577633"
_id: "ZPWNsQ7TWSJcERSJv"
```

Can any one kindly explain to me why this is left out and how to better formulate the query in subject?

Comment: If I understood your requirement, I think it should work if you replace the '$and' with '$or'. This will return all documents that either match payersUserId or recipientNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should work if you replace the following:

```
recipientsDetails.find( { $and: [{payersUserId: user},  {recipientNumber: usersNumber }  ] }  ).fetch();
```

with

```
recipientsDetails.find( { $or: [{payersUserId: user},  {recipientNumber: usersNumber }  ] }  ).fetch();
```